# Heroku H13 error with flask/python app after deployment

Tags: python, http, flask, heroku

I have a flask app that works fine locally and was deployed to Heroku. The home page is accessible and displays properly but when submitting a form that takes the user to another page, the **H13 error** is raised: **Connection closed without response**.

The request takes from 10 to 15 seconds to complete locally but when submitting the form in Heroku, it takes 30 seconds then crashes.

Any idea why the app would deploy to Heroku fine but raises this error when sending a form/changing page ?

Here is the error in the logs:

```
2021-06-01T21:51:53.871045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=the-mgr-project.herokuapp.com request_id=ed08f910-e0b9-4c76-8bb3-3a82cc3ca59e fwd="213.55.220.236" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=9082 protocol=https
2021-06-01T21:51:53.870405+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.79.199.219 - - [01/Jun/2021:21:51:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8927 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
2021-06-01T21:52:30.223394+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:52:30 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:103)
2021-06-01T21:52:31.246525+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:52:31 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 103 was terminated due to signal 9
2021-06-01T21:52:31.250736+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:52:31 +0000] [118] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 118
2021-06-01T21:52:32.360804+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
2021-06-01T21:52:32.360844+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
2021-06-01T21:52:33.043821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/" host=the-mgr-project.herokuapp.com request_id=88d57e33-4d13-4c5b-a11e-d1ef3ee97d2c fwd="213.55.220.236" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33025ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-06-01T21:52:33.983811+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:33.983830+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:33.983899+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:33.983900+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:33.984524+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GridSearchCV from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:33.984525+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:34.008224+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator KNeighborsClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:34.008227+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:34.029465+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:34.029467+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:34.053156+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:34.053159+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:52:34.054204+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:52:34.054206+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:10.332060+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:53:10 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:88)
2021-06-01T21:53:11.362566+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:53:11 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 88 was terminated due to signal 9
2021-06-01T21:53:11.368584+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-01 21:53:11 +0000] [133] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 133
2021-06-01T21:53:11.542838+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/" host=the-mgr-project.herokuapp.com request_id=69126ca8-1e2d-4dab-a27b-f5cd0bdce60a fwd="213.55.220.236" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31491ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-06-01T21:53:12.723118+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
2021-06-01T21:53:12.723129+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004051+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004065+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004129+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator Pipeline from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004129+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004765+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GridSearchCV from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.004766+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.036069+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator KNeighborsClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.036072+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.063638+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.063640+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.090726+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.090730+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-01T21:53:15.091483+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-01T21:53:15.091485+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
```

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

The HTML for the POST method:

```
<form enctype=multipart/form-data action={{url_for('upload_file')}} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <label for="file-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">The music (.wav):</label>
                <input type="file" id="file-input" name="file" class="form-control w-100" required="true"/><br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>Select a model</h4>
                    <input type="radio" id="logreg" name="model" value="logreg" required>
                    <label for="logreg">Logistic regression</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="knn" name="model" value="knn">
                    <label for="knn">K-nearest neighbors</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="randomforest" name="model" value="randomforest">
                    <label for="randomforest">Random forest</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="svm" name="model" value="svm">
                    <label for="svm">Kernel SVM</label><br>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button">
</form>
```

And the app.py file:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    """Main function that gets form infos, extract values from .wav and send result"""

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Get informations from form: file and chosen model
        model = request.form.get("model")
        spec_checkbox = request.form.get("spectrogram")
        chroma_checkbox = request.form.get("chroma")
        tempo_checkbox = request.form.get("tempo")
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        filename = uploaded_file.filename

        # If a file is selected, save it to uploads folder
        if filename == '':
            return 'No file selected'
        else:
            uploaded_file.save(secure_filename(filename))
            track_path = "uploads/" + str(filename)
            shutil.move(filename, track_path)
            print(str(filename) + " has been downloaded and the chosen model is " + str(model))

        # Extract features and remove file from upload folder
        features = extract()
        os.remove(track_path)

        # Call function according to user choice
        if model == 'logreg':
            result_list = logreg(features[0], features[1])
        elif model == 'knn':
            result_list = knn(features[0], features[1])
        elif model == 'randomforest':
            result_list = randomforest(features[0], features[1])
        elif model == 'svm':
            result_list = svm(features[0], features[1])

        text = "Your file " + str(result_list[0]) + "\'s predicted genre is <b style=\"color:red;\">" + str(result_list[1]) + "</b> with the model " + str(result_list[2]) + "!"
        return render_template("results.html", text = text)
```

Here is another edit as after a few more tests, I can see that the app is crashing in when calling the `extract()` function.
It still works locally so I don't really understand why it wouldn't work on heroku.
With some `print` in app.py it is possible to see that the request goes until `extract()` - see error logs:

```
2021-06-02T01:33:20.985460+00:00 app[web.1]: moonlight.wav has been downloaded and the chosen model is logreg
2021-06-02T01:33:20.986694+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator StandardScaler from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-02T01:33:20.986696+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-02T01:33:20.986847+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator PowerTransformer from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2021-06-02T01:33:20.986848+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(
2021-06-02T01:33:20.989981+00:00 app[web.1]: Analyzing file 1 of 1: uploads/moonlight.wav
2021-06-02T01:33:26.229450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/" host=the-mgr-project.herokuapp.com request_id=9c914ee3-3434-41e2-9d77-2d3e2c3cd21d fwd="172.58.140.104" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30104ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-06-02T01:33:26.171668+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-02 01:33:26 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:36)
2021-06-02T01:33:26.230125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-02 01:33:26 +0000] [36] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 36)
2021-06-02T01:33:27.043439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-02 01:33:27 +0000] [44] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 44
```

Comment: Are those the *only* error logs? You will need to find and provide more details. Check for a Traceback on the Heroku logs. There seems to be an error on the POST / route, so maybe sharing the code for that route and adding some logs on that route could help in figuring out what's wrong (does it even run the code on that route? where does it crash?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my question to add the full error logs as well as the HTML form with the request and the app.py.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is working perfectly on localhost try change your Procfile to this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --preload
```